# DDMS Won't Show Debug Output

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ddms

I am currently taking an Android course and I just learned about DDMS and debugging with Logcat.

However, the problem I have is that there are no outputs being shown on DDMS whenever I run the program on the emulator (using Eclipse IDE)

Here is my code

```
package com.fv.android.practice.project;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String DEBUGTAG = "FV";
public static final String TEXTFILE = "notesquirrel.txt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addSaveButtonListener();
}

private void addSaveButtonListener() {
    Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);

            String text = editText.getText().toString();


                Log.d(DEBUGTAG, "Save button clicked: " + text);
            }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:maxLength="400"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Enter Your Text Here" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

When I type something into the "note" app, I should have some sort of output saying that I typed something, but I have zero output from the DDMS. Nothing at all. What can I do to fix this? I already went to the manifest and tried to set Debuggable to true but Eclipse tells me not to hardcode the debugging process, or something like that.

Also, I checked to see if the emulator was selected for debugging in the DDMS, and it is.

Comment: The only log statement I see is when you catch an Exception from trying to write to a file. Do you have other log statements elsewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: @Tanis.7x I've edited it. Just now. The code was different before, but there has been no output whatsoever from the DDMS.

Comment: Have you tried restarting DDMS? What happens if you run `adb logcat` from the command line?

Comment: @Tanis.7x I tried restarting DDMS and nothing changed. No output still. I don't know how to run adb logcat from the command line

Comment: Assuming that adb is in your path, you can just type `adb logcat` and hit enter. If adb isn't in your path, you can navigate to whatever directory your Android SDK is in, open the `platform-tools` folder, and run the same command.

Comment: @Tanis.7x OK. I found it. Also,I restarted DDMS again. I am now getting output. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Now using Android Studio.